# How let I do Dart something every second?

Tags: dart

I want to call a funktion every second. I tried this but it did not worked:

```
void main() {
    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.start();
    int counter = 0;
    while (true) {
        if ((stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds / 1000) >= counter) {
            counter += 1;
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Timer](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Timer) class.

```
main() {
  int counter = 0;
  new Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    counter +=1;
  // do something
  });
}
```